# tensorflow object detection api export empty variable folder

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection, tensorflow-serving

I tried to export the saved_model for tensorflow serving by

```
python object_detection/export_inference_graph.py \
    --input_type encoded_image_string_tensor \
    --pipeline_config_path ${OBJECT_DETECTION_CONFIG} \
    --trained_checkpoint_prefix ${YOUR_LOCAL_CHK_DIR}/model.ckpt-${CHECKPOINT_NUMBER} \
    --output_directory ${YOUR_LOCAL_EXPORT_DIR}
```

But it exported an empty folder for the variables.

How to modify the code to make it work?

Comment: Can you add some more information? Did you edit the `export_inference_graph.py` script or are you using it 'out of the box'. Is there a reason you are using the `input_type` as `encoded_image_string_tensor`? It's supposed to work out of the box. Is there a error messege shown after running the script?

Comment: Please take a look to this GitHub issue: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/1988 This helped me when I tried to overcome the same problem.